# Highlight the corresponding line number with another datasets

Tags: sas

I have two datasets, one extract the extreme values from proc univariate. I would like to create a new variable and label them as 1 if the *n* in the original dataset equals the extracted line number in the univariate dataset. But I don't know how to program it not manually enter the line number.
[image]

Comment: Hi! Please don't post screenshots, but instead post code as text.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There're a few ways to do this, but one easy way is to just add the rownum to the original dataset and merge on it.

Here's an example.

```
ods output extremeobs=extreme_test;
proc univariate data=sashelp.heart;
run;
ods output close;

data extreme_diastolic extreme_systolic;  *just creating the extreme datasets;
  set extreme_test;
  if varname='Diastolic' then output extreme_diastolic;
  else if varname='Systolic' then output extreme_systolic;
run;

data for_merge;    *adding rownum on to the original dataset;
  set sashelp.heart;
  rownum = _n_;
run;


*now, sort the extreme datasets by the `highobs` and `lowobs` values respectively and save those as `rownum`, so they can be merged;

proc sort data=extreme_diastolic out=high_diastolic(keep=highobs rename=highobs=rownum); 
  by highobs;
run;

proc sort data=extreme_systolic out=high_systolic(keep=highobs rename=highobs=rownum);
  by highobs;
run;

proc sort data=extreme_diastolic out=low_diastolic(keep=lowobs rename=lowobs=rownum); 
  by lowobs;
run;

proc sort data=extreme_systolic out=low_systolic(keep=lowobs rename=lowobs=rownum);
  by lowobs;
run;

*now, merge those on using `in=` to identify which are matches.;

data heart_extremes;
  merge for_merge high_diastolic(in=_highd) high_systolic(in=_highs) low_diastolic(in=_lowd) low_systolic(in=_lows);
  by rownum;
  if _highd then high_diastolic = 1;
  if _highs then high_systolic = 1;
  if _lowd then low_diastolic = 1;
  if _lows then low_systolic = 1;
run;
```